# Python problems with error handling (try, except)

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, try-catch

I'm new to programming and trying to work out the error handling at the moment.
But i keep running into the same problem. When I find an error i want to rerun the script again. The problem is, if you enter a good input after the first mistake, it still sees it as a bad input. please help me out.

```
def new_user_name()
    print "Choose a Username"
    username = input_str()

    try: 
        data = lite.connect(database)
        dat = data.cursor()
        dat.execute("INSERT INTO Users('User_Name') VALUES(?)", username);
        dat.rollback()
        return username
    except: 
        print "The username %s is already in use" % username
        time.sleep(2)
        new_user_name()
```

Can someone help me out, or link a nice tutorial about errorhandling?
It would me help out alot

Comment: **Never** use a plain `except:`. **Always** specify which exceptions you want to catch, in your case something like `except OperationalError:`. Otherwise you'll silence the wrong error thus producing some strange and hard to debug bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a great official documentation, links are below:

v 2.7 http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html
v 3.3 http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/errors.html

Please notice you must never use `except:` without Exception class, it is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

`dat.rollback()` (if this is a valid syntax, didn't check but looks close) should be in the except section and not in the try section.

Notice that you should be better of if you initiliazed the database connection outside the function (so you won't have to do it every function call) or at least outside the try section.

Comment: dat.rollback() works so i assume it is the right syntax for it. The reason why I use it like that is because later in my code the whole data will be written to the database. (Username, Password, email and more) Since the username is unique, I remove it after testing. But thanks for the tip. Will get my connection outside the try

Answer (score 0):

```
dat.execute("INSERT INTO Users('User_Name') VALUES(?)", username);
```

This line is the problem. The second argument should be a tuple, not a string, so it's raising a `ValueError`. Because you're catching all errors instead of just `sqlite3.IntegrityError` (which would be raised if you tried to insert a duplicate primary key), you will always end up in the `except` block.

Never use catch-all `except` blocks if you can avoid it.